# How to order group_by data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to create a graph out of a Placements model which is comprised of a businesses employees.

I use the following code:

```
def self.chart_data(business)
 business.placements.order(:month).group_by(&:month).map  do |month, data|
  hash = {month: month.strftime("%Y-%m")}
  data.each {|placement| hash[placement.employee.name] = placement.position}
  JSON.parse(hash.to_json)
 end
end
```

To produce the following data:

```
[{"month"=>"01/2014", "John"=>3, "Glen"=>4, "Frank"=>5}, {"month"=>"02/2014", "John"=>1, "Glen"=>2, "Frank"=>3}]
```

I now need to specify the labels for the graph, which will be the names of the employees.

How can I do this while keeping the same order of employee names? i.e.

```
["John", "Glen", "Frank"]
```

If I get the names of employees per business then the names are out of order relative to the Placement data:

```
@business.employees.pluck(:name)

["Frank", "John", "Glen"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
chart_data = Placement.chart_data(@business)
employees_names = chart_data.flat_map(&:keys).uniq.select{ |name| name.to_s != 'month' }
# should return
# => ["John", "Glen", "Frank"]
```